# Getting a "error creating userdata cloudinit file on FAT partition" on Rpi Imager while writing ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, readwrite, raspberry-pi-imager

trying to write a UBUNTU SERVER 22.04.01 for a raspberry PI 400 but it is always giving this error regardless of what SD card I use.
Steps:

1. Launch Rpi Imager
2. Select General OS -> Ubuntu -> Ubuntu Server 22.04.01 ARM64
3. Select SD Card
4. click the setting gear button to provide username/password SSID/password saves and exits
5. clicks on the write button
6. wait for writing the image and then observe the issue

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I have tried this with 2 SD cards but the issue persists. The user data like usernames/passwords don't get written on the image and must be set again after the first login. As the card gets locked, I can't set up the network-config file.
Help is appreciated

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that the imager knows how all the images work. It is designed for Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: PS last time I tried Ubuntu server it DID NOT support WiFi

Comment: I used to work on the server. It used to support WiFi and and imager knows how ubuntu works